# Create access control in hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I am using golang and node SDK for  the chain code and server respectively. How can I implement access control, should I use programmatic access control in the chain code or is there any declarative access control like Appkication ACL in hyperledger composer.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version i.e. 1.1 there is provision of access control based on the extra arguments in the certificate, where while executing the chaincode , it can look for that argument in the certificate and execute accordingly. And there is data encryption support as well.

Comment: Can you please share any documents related to this?

Comment: Attribute Based Access Control: http://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#attribute-based-access-control . Check out fabric 1.1 release notes for further info: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/releases.html